# Get Delta Live Tables running

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks, delta-live-tables

I am pretty new to Databricks Delta Live tables and I built a small use case to test how it works.
Therefore I've created 2 tables, which I want to join in the notebook and then write the joined table into a 3rd table. Bc I want to test the APPLY CHANGES TO function I want to merge the joined result into this 3rd table. This table is currently empty and I tried this code in my notebook, but it does not work. The error is: **Update 5a190f is FAILED**.

The script looks like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    distinct a.PK,
    a.Value AS first_name,
    b.VALUE AS last_name
  FROM xx_xxx_xxx_dev.sandbox.tablea AS A
  JOIN xx_xxx_xxx_dev.sandbox.tableb AS B ON a.PK = b.FK
)

APPLY CHANGES INTO xx_xxx_xxx_dev.sandbox.joined_table
FROM cte
KEY (PK)
;
```

I have the feeling I am missing a lot of things here, so any help is highly appreciated. The configuration of the pipeline is this:

[Pipeline Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2w1X.png)

I've tried first to create the table if not exist in the notebook, but this didn't work, so I've created the table in the schema which is referenced in the pipeline settings as target schema.
I played with semicolons, but I do not have any clue tbh if there have to be some between the 2 blocks of cte and apply changes part.
The tables which are joined are just regular tables in the schema.

Comment: please post the full error that you can obtain if you click on the message about failed update

Comment: Has been a permissions issue. Moreover I learned, that you have to define the unity catalog as a destination and I cannot use the CTE just in my query I need to use LIVE tables. Then it does work besides the APPLY CHANGES INTO, which is giving me this error: 
== SQL ==
APPLY CHANGES INTO live.apply_changes_table
from live.joined_live_table_2
Keys (primary_key)
------------------^^^

for this SQL:
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING TABLE apply_changes_table;

APPLY CHANGES INTO live.apply_changes_table
from live.joined_live_table_2
Keys (primary_key); -- primary_key is valid in the table